# D3 v4: spacing between and binding of elements of arbitrarily complex array with nested g tags

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, svg

## TL;DR

Aim: Be able to space arbitrary groupings with variable spacer size dependent upon the level of the grouping where:

- objects are correspondingly grouped in `<g>` tags
- the spacing of objects / groups have incremental translations in their respective `<g>` tags
- bind, enter, update, and exit work at the correct nested levels

in a recursive function.

Currently have: recursive function that:

- correctly nests objects
- correctly spaces these objects
- incorrectly updates when given new data

---

While this question about spacing is easily generalizable to other types of charts (e.g. violin, box-whisker, even rendering axes), for the sake of simplicity let us approach this problem in the context of making a simple bar chart.

We will have our data be represented in an array, where a numerical value corresponds to the height of the bar and an array corresponds to a group.

For example, if we had two pairs of two data points, we could produce a grouped bar chart like so:

```
[[1,4],[3,2]]
```

would produce:

[image]

and

```
[2, [3,5], [[1,4,3], 2]]
```

would produce:

[image]

Now the first example is more likely to occur in practice, e.g. comparing value a and value b between group x and group y. The latter one is harder to see a concrete example, but in practice and spacing function worth it's salt should handle arbitrarily complex groupings. Most likely you would have equally nested groupings than un-equal as demonstrated here.

Nonetheless, in example 2, it is clear that each element at "level 0" (`2`, `[3,5]` , and `[[1,4,3],2]`) have an equally sized, and large spacer between them. For elements at "level 1" (`3`, and `5` as well as `[1,4,3]` and `2`), there is a smaller spacer, and for elements at "level 2" (`1`, `4`, and `3`) there is the smallest spacer.

Some things to note:

- each of these images are produced by code in this example (so I am close to the desired answer)
- I am using the term "level" to refer to the depth of nesting a value occurs at and since JS is 0-indexed, elements in the main array are at level 0, etc.
- in this example, my default coloring function colors each bar by its index in relation to its parent (again - each bar occurs in a nesting of `<g>` tags corresponding to the nesting seen in the passed array).
- "arbitrary complexity" - here - refers to an array consisting of numerical values and arrays of numerical values only (e.g. nested arrays)

So to sum it up the:

## GOAL:

Given an array of arbitrary complexity, create an equivalent grouping in an SVG spaced by the level at which the value occurs with the corresponding translation occurring at the respective group (`<g>` tag). In addition have the data binding not require the complete removal of existing elements, when the function is recalled with different data.

## Path to where we are now

(see above images)

Currently we have the recursion, the nested groups and the correct translation working. What is left is correcting the bind, enter, update, exit functions.

### Iteration 1 - just get the spacing down

#### Example:

Given the following demo array

```
demo = [1,1,1,1,[2,2,2],[[3,3],[[4,4,4]]], 1]
```

could be spaced as follows

[image]

where each level is colored separately (e.g. the first level is black, and we see 5 black squares for the first four 1s in the array and the last 1 in the array).

How to reproduce example

The image above can be calculated by recursively moving each element of all levels by:

- the number of **non**-array elements at any level that come before it * width of the rendered elements
- the cumulative amount of "spacer" between each element (non-array inclusive)

The spacer at any level can be defined as:

```
1 / (level + 1) // assuming zero indexed e.g. the lowest level is level 0
                // where the 1s are in the demo array
```

To get an array of the total amount of spacer that comes before the *non*-array element at index *i* I wrote this recursive function:

```
function cumulativeSpacer(array, level, cSpacerData, cSpacer) {
  level = level == undefined ? 0 : level
  cSpacerData = cSpacerData == undefined ? [] : d
  cSpacer = cSpacer == undefined ? 0 : cSpacer
  a.map(function(arr, ind){
    if ( ind == 0 ) { cSpacer }
    else {cSpacer += (1 / (level+1))}


    if (Array.isArray(arr)) {cumulativeSpacer(arr, level+1, cSpacerData, cSpacer); cSpacer = cSpacerData.last()}
    else {cSpacerData.push(cSpacer)}
  })
  return cSpacerData
}
```

Which if we run with the demo array we get:

```
Array [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4.5, 5, 6, 6.333333333333333, 6.833333333333333, 7.083333333333333, 7.333333333333333, 8.333333333333332 ]
```

The first element of a level is *not* shifted by a spacer i.e. at a given level with length *n* there are *n*-1 spacers.

### Iteration 2 - move the spacing to the `<g>`

While the above function works, I would like to change the recursion.

For those familiar with SVG, they are aware of the group `<g>` tag. Lets assume that I have placed each element in nested groups (one for each level of the element). Then I would like to calculate the translation on each group tag instead, rather than on the elements themselves.

e.g.

```
<g level=0>
    <rect...>        (element index: 0, value: 1)
</g>
<g level=0>
    <rect...>        (element index: 1, value: 1)
</g>
<g level=0>
    <rect...>        (element index: 2, value: 1)
</g>
<g level=0>
    <rect...>        (element index: 3, value: 1)
</g>
<g level=0>
    <g level=1>
        <rect...>    (element index: 4, value: 2)
    </g>
    <g level=1>
        <rect...>    (element index: 5, value: 2)
    </g>
    <g level=1>
        <rect...>    (element index: 6, value: 2)
    </g>
    <rect...>
</g>
...
```

Function for producing nested groups

```
function createNestedGroups(selection, data, objClass, level, index) {
  var currentSelection = selection.selectAll('g[level="'+level+'"]')
  currentSelection = currentSelection.data(data)
  currentSelection.exit().remove()
  index = index == undefined ? 0 : index
  currentSelection = currentSelection.enter().append('g').attr('level', level)
  currentSelection.each(function(currentData, index) {
    var t = d3.select(this)
    if (Array.isArray(currentData)) { createNestedGroups(t, currentData, objClass, level+1, index)}
    else { t.append('g').attr('class', objClass) }
  })
  return level
}
```

Thus if we have:

createNestedGroups(d3.select('g.test'), demo, 'item-container')

will produce the above nested grouping

then we can achieve the coloring by:

```
d3.select('g.test').selectAll('g.item-container').each(function(d, i) {
      var t = d3.select(this)
      var b = t.select('rect').empty() ? t.append('rect') : t.select('rect')
      b.attr('width', 10)
      b.attr('height', 10)
      .attr('fill', function(dd, k) {
          var l = d3.select(t.node().parentNode).attr('level')
          if (l == 0) {return "black"}
          if (l == 1) {return "blue"}
          if (l == 2) {return "red"}
          if (l == 3) {return "purple"}
        })
    })
```

If we update `makeNestedGroups` to try and incorporate the movement:

```
function makeNestedGroups(selection, data, objectClass, objectSize, spacerSize, level, cumulativeIndex, cumulativeSpacer, m) {
  if (cumulativeSpacer == undefined) {console.log('type\tlevel\tindex\tcumI\tcumSL\tcumS');}
  cumulativeIndex = cumulativeIndex == undefined ? 0 : cumulativeIndex
  cumulativeSpacer = cumulativeSpacer == undefined ? 0 : cumulativeSpacer
  m = m == undefined ? 0:m
  // bind, remove, update, and append new groups for the current level
  var currentSelection = selection.selectAll('g[level="'+level+'"]')
  currentSelection = currentSelection.data(data)
  currentSelection.exit().remove()
  currentSelection = currentSelection.enter().append('g').attr('level', level)

  var cumulativeSpacerAtLevel = 0

  currentSelection.each(function(currentElement, index) {
    var t = d3.select(this)


    if (index) {cumulativeSpacerAtLevel += spacerSize * 1 / (level+1)}
    // if (level == 1) {console.log(m, cumulativeSpacer, cumulativeSpacerAtLevel)}

    // if (index) { move += baseSpacerSize * 1 / (level+1) * index}

    if (Array.isArray(currentElement)) {
      // console.log("HERE")
      // console.log(level, index, cumulativeSpacer)
      [cumulativeIndex, cumulativeSpacer, m] = makeNestedGroups(t, currentElement, objectClass, objectSize, spacerSize, level+1, cumulativeIndex, cumulativeSpacerAtLevel,m)
      m += cumulativeSpacer
      t.attr('transform', 'translate('+m+',0)')
      console.log("ARR", level, index, cumulativeIndex, cumulativeSpacerAtLevel, cumulativeSpacer)
    }
    else {
      // m  = cumulativeIndex * objectSize
      // m += cumulativeSpacerAtLevel
      console.log()
      //          t.attr('transform', 'translate('+m+',0)')

      t.append('g').attr('class', objectClass);
      // currentElement is not an array, update collectiveIndex
      console.log("NOT", level, index, cumulativeIndex, cumulativeSpacerAtLevel, cumulativeSpacer)
      cumulativeIndex += 1
      m += objectSize
    }

  })

  return [cumulativeIndex, cumulativeSpacer + cumulativeSpacerAtLevel, m]
}
```

then (with the commented out lines) we see that most of the elements are moved over correctly for the number of proceeding elements.

However getting this to work as before for some reason has become obscure to me.

e.g. the last element in the array `demo` (a 1), needs to be moved over `6 * level_0 spacer` + `3 * level_1 spacer` + `1 * level_2 spacer` +`2 *level_3 spacer`

as there are:

- 6 elements proceeding it at level 0
- 5 items at level 1 (`2,2,2, [3,3], [[4,4,4]]`) but 3 spacers need for them
- 3 items at level 2 (`3,3, [4,4,4]`) but 1 spacer needed between them
- 3 items at level 3 (`4,4,4`) but 2 spacers between them

### Iteration 3 - correcting iteration 2

This function produces the desired group nesting as well as the corresponding translates at each group level:

```
function makeNestedGroups(
  selection,           // container where levels are to be added
  data,                // list of aribtrary number of mixed numbers and lists
  horizontalQ,         // whether it should be spaced horizontallly or vertically 
  scale,               // scale for the values in the list
  objectClass,         // what the container for the object be
  objectSize,          // object size
  spacerSize,          // base size to move object over by
  level,               // current level (nesting)
  transitionDuration,  // how long transitions should take
  easeFunc             // transition easing function
) {

  // default value for level
  if ( horizontalQ == undefined ) { horizontalQ = true; }
  if ( level == undefined ) { level = 0;  }
  if ( transitionDuration == undefined ) { transitionDuration=1000; }
  if ( easeFunc == undefined ) { easeFunc = d3.easeExp; }


  /*
  *  NEED HELP HERE
  */ 

  // select all current level groups
  var currentSelection = selection.selectAll('g[level="'+level+'"]')
  // bind data
  currentSelection = currentSelection.data(data)
  // add new group for all sub elements
  var enter = currentSelection.enter().append('g').attr('level', level)
  // remove excess
  var exit = currentSelection.exit().remove()
  currentSelection = currentSelection.merge(enter)


  // removes too much
  selection.selectAll(':not([level="'+level+'"])').remove()


  // spacer for current level
  var levelSpacer = spacerSize / (level+1)

  // movement for current level
  var move =  0
  currentSelection.each(function(currentElement, index) {
    // this selection
    var t = d3.select(this)


    // move container
    t.transition().duration(transitionDuration).ease(easeFunc)
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) { 
      var 
      x = horizontalQ ? move : 0, 
      y = !horizontalQ ? move: 0, 
      t = 'translate('+x+','+y+')'
      return t
    })


    // If currentElement is an array ---> recurse
    if (Array.isArray(currentElement)) {
      move += makeNestedGroups(t, currentElement, horizontalQ, scale, objectClass, objectSize, spacerSize, level+1,transitionDuration, easeFunc)
    }
    else {
      // move over by object size
      move += objectSize
      // grab object
      var obj = t.select('g[level="'+level+'"] > g.'+objectClass).attr('parent-index', index).attr('data', currentElement)

      if (obj.empty()) { // if empty, add
        obj = t.append('g')
        .attr('class', objectClass)
        .attr('parent-index', index)
      }
    } // end else for if cur is array

    // move over by a spacer if not last element
    move += (index == currentSelection.size()-1) ? 0 : levelSpacer
  })
  return move
}
```

but if I call with a different array structure, then I get duplicate boxes sometimes, or it removes all boxes and recreates them.

The issue in iteration 2 was that it is insufficient to count the number of elements at a level seen so far and make inferences to the amount of spacers needed. If there are two elements at level 1, and each are in their own array, then there are 0 spacers at level 1 needed between them.

## What is left?

Fixing the bind, enter, update, and exit

In iteration 3 I point out:

```
  /*
  *  NEED HELP HERE
  */ 

  // select all current level groups
  var currentSelection = selection.selectAll('g[level="'+level+'"]')
  // bind data
  currentSelection = currentSelection.data(data)
  // add new group for all sub elements
  var enter = currentSelection.enter().append('g').attr('level', level)
  // remove excess
  var exit = currentSelection.exit().remove()
  currentSelection = currentSelection.merge(enter)


  // removes too much
  selection.selectAll(':not([level="'+level+'"])').remove()
```

It is clear to me why this is a mistake.

For those who might be a bit befuddled, the issue stems from the desire to handle *arbitrary* complexity (e.g. mixed values and nested arrays).

In addition, it stems from my own desire to nest data in `<g>` tags.

The selection for all `<g level="currentLevel">` tags include a mix between `<g class=objectClass>` and `<g level="currentLevel+1">` tags.

So if `data1` had in total 5 bars, and `data2` had in total 7 bars (each at their own arbitrary nesting) then having the 5 bars from `data1` translate over to the location of the first 5 bars of `data2` is not as straightforward if they do not correspond to the same nesting.

Thus I think a more careful selection needs to be made *or* elements need to be bound, entered, updated, and exited individually.

Despite seeing this error, it is unclear to me the most efficient solution to getting the desired nested and removal of elements without producing duplicates with a different nested structure.

Note for @Christoph

Foremost, I appreciate your answer, tips, and time invested in helping me find a solution. I think, however, there is a bit of a misunderstanding.

The function I provided was an generalization for spacing any complex grouping. The function could space grouped violin plots, grouped box-and-whiskers and other object that require more than a single element because it adds `<objectClass>` to the nested `g` such that one can then call `<container-selection>.selectAll(g.<objectClass>)` and then `.each(function(d, i) {... /*make whatever crazy data-driven shape here.*/})` to make whatever they want. In addition, this recursive spacing is also a generalization as many bl.ocks with grouped bars / violins will have variables such as `innerSpacer` and `outerSpacer`; I find that approach rather clunky and not robust.

I do agree that the plotting functions should just "plot" the data; In accordance, at no point does this function over-reach into pre-processing the data. The code I provided here is a M.W.E. to produce the spacers elements and produce the incorrect binding... it just doesn't show any shape as that is a *different function* (checking if the selection is empty and then appending if needed is straight-forward) and my closures for this (the entire bar plot) are too large to fit in this already lengthy question.

In my closures there are the data in a use-able "flat" form and the `grouping` variable specifying how the data should be ordered / grouped.

The point is, that the function as I provided was abstracted enough that you could build an equally flexible function on top of it, which is the goal - re-use (as Bostock often emphasizes). I hope it is clear to you how instead of appending a `rect` (as you opted for), the `g.<objectClass>` means this function can be reused in bars plot, violing plots, etc.

As for data-models I think we can both agree that the ones we provided here are just short hand simplifications for demo / debug purposes.

As for updating the spacing the function - as I provided it - does that already if called a second time. That was not the issue. The issue and this question is about **nested** `g` tags.

You state they are nu-necessary. That is kind-of true. To just get the spacing right, absolutely. It is much easier (and more natural) to calculate the recursive spacing without the nesting than with (hence it being a later iteration); however, it is not hard to image a use-case where one would like to highlight, drag, move, or apply any other event on a nested **group**. In which case, which implementation is it easier to apply? The flatten version (as you implemented and I did originally) or the nested version? It is the latter (unless you enjoy working with parentNodes, which is still somewhat clunky in `d3`).

So the short of it:
- thank you. I appreciate your time, effort, input and answer. +1.
- it is not the answer to the question asked. Even for the nested answer, you just added bars, but it still removes too much.

Two ways one could try to make solve answer:

1. check on layer ahead and move children to new parents as needed
2. check on layer ahead and remove any element that might not belong (what I currently have implemented)

and admittedly the former (most likely more challenge) will yield nicer transitions (in my opinion).

The difference is that in `1` bars that already exist (in any level of grouping) are re purposed for bars in the new data and in `2` only bars under the same level are reused if that level exists for the new data.

Comment: What is the meaning of the variables `a` and `d` in `cumulativeSpacer`?

Comment: @Christoph a is array and d is cSpacerData. Stuff I missed in copy-paste + make more explicit

Comment: Sorry, I have to little time at the moment to really provide an answer to your question. The offered methods don't show how you finally render the bars but concentrate on calculate the shifts within groups. It actually seems to work, just render a rect with dimensions around `if (obj.empty()) { // if empty, add
                obj = t.append('rect')`. And take another thought of d3 meaning data driven documents. Prepare the data upfront and render it seperately. Take a look at https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/ and http://bl.ocks.org/alansmithy/e984477a741bc56db5a5. 'joins' are the key to d3.

Comment: @Christoph correct, because this function could be used for any type of categorical data / object. So after the function call you `selectAll(<objectClass>)` and render the bar,violin,etc without worrying about translations. The bars I made are a demo using this function - which works for spacing - but the nested <g> elements get messed up on repeated calls with different data. Idk what you want to say w the last two sentences. This function doesn't prepare data, just spaces it and yes, joins are the crux of the question, hence the bind, enter, update, merge, and exit used in the code...

Comment: @Christoph anyway the data binding gets difficult for having nested elements because you need to select outside of the nesting and then append into correct nest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record *an* answer to my question was in my original post.

I opened a bounty as I was not satisfied with my own solution at the time as it removed too many elements; namely, elements that would be replaced in the same spot (or called with the same data) were removed, which was obvious when these elements had transitions for their shape.

A more targeted `remove` would be to remove the line:

```
selection.selectAll(':not([level="'+level+'"])').remove();
```

and add in :

```
currentSelection.each(function(d, i){
  ...
  if (Array.isArray(currentElement)) {
    move += makeNestedGroups(t, currentElement, horizontalQ, scale, moveby, objectClass, objectSize, spacerSize, level+1,transitionDuration, easeFunc)


    // BEGIN: add
    t.selectAll('g[level="'+(level)+'"] > g.'+objectClass).remove()
    // END: add


  }

  else {
  ...
  // BEGIN: add
  t.selectAll('g[level="'+(level+1)+'"]').remove()
  // END: add
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After a small modification your code is working. Changed append('g') to append('rect'), added colors and dimensions and called it from a d3.interval (see https://jsfiddle.net/w0wLgz3x/).

```
// snippet from makeNestedGroups, last iteration
if (obj.empty()) { // if empty, add
    obj = t.append('rect')
       .attr('class', objectClass)
       .attr('height', function(d) {
           return d * 20;
       })
       .attr('fill', function(d) {
           return colors[d%3];
       })
       .attr('width', function(d) {
           return 10;
       })
       .attr('parent-index', index);
```

To clarify my mention of a more data-driven approach I also added a suggestion, which - I have to admit - does not generate all the groups within the SVG, as they are not needed (you could change the code to fit your needs).

The benefit of this approach is clear separation of concerns. The data model is changed by your business logic and the d3 part just deals with displaying the data (Model-View-Controller), which makes each part easier to understand.

In short, you define your data model

```
var a = { id: 1, height: 10, color: 'red', offset: 0};
var b = { id: 2, height: 20, color: 'green', offset: 0 };
var c = { id: 3, height: 50, color: 'orange', offset: 0 };
var d = { id: 4, height: 40, color: 'blue', offset: 0 };
var e = { id: 5, height: 50, color: 'black', offset: 0 };
var nodes = [ a, b, c, d ];
```

and the possible groupings

```
var datasets2 = [{
   order: [ a, [b, c], d ],
   visible: [ a, b, c, d ]
}, {
    order: [ a, d ],
    visible: [ a, d ]
}, {
    order: [ a, [ b, c ], d ],
    visible: [ a, b, c, d ]
}, {
    order: [ [a,  b], [d , c] ],
    visible: [ a, b, c, d ]
}];
```

To apply a grouping you have to update the offsets in the data model. This is done recursively, while the recursion keeps track of the current offset. I wrapped up everything in the function Bars with global `spacing` and the helper functions `first` and `rest` (see fiddle).

```
function Bars() {}
// Update the offsets according to the dataset.order
Bars.prototype.update = function(data) {
    // recursive update
    function rec(head, tail, level, offset) {
        if (Array.isArray(head)) {
            // add larger spacing around groups
            offset += spacing/2;
            offset = rec(first(head), rest(head), level + 1, offset);
            offset += spacing/2;
            if(tail.length > 0) {
                    return rec(first(tail), rest(tail), level, offset);
            } else {
                return offset;
            }
        } else {
            offset = offset + spacing;
            head.offset = offset;
            head.level = level;
            if(tail.length > 0) {
                offset = rec(first(tail), rest(tail), level, offset);
            }
            return offset;
        }
    }
    rec(first(data), rest(data), 1, 20);
    return data;
}
```

The rendering of the bars is performed within a d3.interval.

```
d3.interval(function() {
    var mod = datasets2.length;
    var current = datasets2[(i++ % mod)];
    var data = update(current.order);
    console.log("-- ", i % mod, current);
    console.log(nodes.map(function(x) { return  x.id + ": " +  x.offset;  }));
    var bars = g.selectAll('rect')
            .data(current.visible);
    bars.exit().remove();
    bars.enter()
        .append('rect')
        .merge(bars)
        .attr('height', function(d) {
            return d.height;
        })
        .attr('width', function(d) {
            return d.width || 10;
        })
        .attr('fill', function(d) {
            return d.color;
        })
        //.style('opacity', 0.5)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
            var x = d.offset,
                y = 0;
            return 'translate('+ x +','+ 0 +')';
        });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer and the fiddle. Please see comment in the O.P.